# Traefik not showing IP Address

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I am very new to Docker and I am trying to use/configure Docker using [docker4wordpress](https://github.com/wodby/docker4wordpress).

However I am not getting any IP address for Traefik I should be getting the server public IP address if I am thinking correctly - I am running this on a Linode server.  I should then be able to access via `portainer.sub.domain.co.nz:port`.

```
turtle_traefik_1     /traefik -c /dev/null --we ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp
```

**Composer file:**

```
version: "2"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:10.2-3.0.2
#    image: wodby/mariadb:10.1-3.0.2
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
#    volumes:
#      - ./mariadb-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # Place init .sql file(s) here.
#      - /path/to/mariadb/data/on/host:/var/lib/mysql # I want to manage volumes manually.

#  postgres:
#    image: wodby/postgres:10.1-1.2.0
##    image: wodby/postgres:9.6-1.2.0
#    environment:
#      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
#      POSTGRES_DB: wordpress
#      POSTGRES_USER: wordpress
#    volumes:
#      - ./postgres-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # Place init file(s) here.
#      - /path/to/postgres/data/on/host:/var/lib/postgresql/data # I want to manage volumes manually.

  php:
# 1. Images with vanilla WordPress – wodby/wordpress:[WP_VERSION]-[PHP_VERSION]-[STABILITY_TAG].
    image: wodby/wordpress:4-7.2-3.3.1
#    image: wodby/wordpress:4-7.1-3.3.1
#    image: wodby/wordpress:4-7.0-3.3.1
#    image: wodby/wordpress:4-5.6-3.3.1
# 2. Images without WordPress – wodby/wordpress-php:[PHP_VERSION]-[STABILITY_TAG].
#    image: wodby/wordpress-php:7.2-3.3.1
#    image: wodby/wordpress-php:7.1-3.3.1
#    image: wodby/wordpress-php:7.0-3.3.1
#    image: wodby/wordpress-php:5.6-3.3.1
# 3. Images without WordPress – wodby/wordpress-php:[PHP_VERSION]-[STABILITY_TAG].Version for development (--enable-debug)
#    image: wodby/wordpress-php:7.2-dev-3.3.1
#    image: wodby/wordpress-php:7.1-dev-3.3.1
#    image: wodby/wordpress-php:7.0-dev-3.3.1
#    image: wodby/wordpress-php:5.6-dev-3.3.1
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      PHP_FPM_CLEAR_ENV: "no"
#      PHP_XDEBUG: 1
#      PHP_XDEBUG_DEFAULT_ENABLE: 1
#      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK: 0
#      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: "10.254.254.254"
#      PHP_XDEBUG_PROFILER_OUTPUT_DIR: /mnt/files/xdebug/profiler
#      PHP_XDEBUG_TRACE_OUTPUT_DIR: /mnt/files/xdebug/traces
    volumes:
      - codebase:/var/www/html
## Options for macOS users (http://docs.docker4wordpress.org/en/latest/macos)
#      - codebase:/var/www/html:cached # User-guided caching
#      - docker-sync:/var/www/html # Docker-sync
## For Xdebug profiler files
#      - files:/mnt/files

  nginx:
    image: wodby/wordpress-nginx:4-1.13-3.0.2
#    image: wodby/wordpress-nginx:4-1.12-3.0.2
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_CONTENT_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
    volumes:
      - codebase:/var/www/html
# Options for macOS users (http://docs.docker4wordpress.org/en/latest/macos)
#      - codebase:/var/www/html:cached # User-guided caching
#      - docker-sync:/var/www/html # Docker-sync
    depends_on:
      - php
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=nginx'
      - 'traefik.port=80'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:sub.domain.co.nz'

#  apache:
#    image: wodby/php-apache:2.4-2.0.2
#    depends_on:
#      - php
#    environment:
#      APACHE_LOG_LEVEL: debug
#      APACHE_BACKEND_HOST: php
#      APACHE_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html
#    volumes:
#      - codebase:/var/www/html
## Options for macOS users (http://docs.docker4wordpress.org/en/latest/macos)
##      - codebase:/var/www/html:cached # User-guided caching
##      - docker-sync:/var/www/html # Docker-sync
#    labels:
#      - 'traefik.backend=apache'
#      - 'traefik.port=80'
#      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:sub.domain.co.nz'

  varnish:
    image: wodby/wordpress-varnish:4.1-2.3.1
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    environment:
      VARNISH_SECRET: secret
      VARNISH_BACKEND_HOST: nginx
      VARNISH_BACKEND_PORT: 80
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=varnish'
      - 'traefik.port=6081'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:varnish.sub.domain.co.nz'

#  redis:
    image: wodby/redis:4.0-2.1.4
#    image: wodby/redis:3.2-2.1.4

#  pma:
#    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
#    environment:
#      PMA_HOST: mariadb
#      PMA_USER: wordpress
#      PMA_PASSWORD: wordpress
#      PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 1G
#      PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS: 1G
#    labels:
#      - 'traefik.backend=pma'
#      - 'traefik.port=80'
#      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:pma.tinyturtles.co.nz'

#  athenapdf:
#    image: arachnysdocker/athenapdf-service:2.10.0
#    environment:
#      WEAVER_AUTH_KEY: weaver-auth-key
#      WEAVER_ATHENA_CMD: "athenapdf -S"
#      WEAVER_MAX_WORKERS: 10
#      WEAVER_MAX_CONVERSION_QUEUE: 50
#      WEAVER_WORKER_TIMEOUT: 90
#      WEAVER_CONVERSION_FALLBACK: false

#  blackfire:
#    image: blackfire/blackfire
#    environment:
#      BLACKFIRE_SERVER_ID: XXXXX
#      BLACKFIRE_SERVER_TOKEN: YYYYY

#  webgrind:
#    image: wodby/webgrind:1.5-1.0.0
#    environment:
#      WEBGRIND_PROFILER_DIR: /mnt/files/xdebug/profiler
#    labels:
#      - 'traefik.backend=webgrind'
#      - 'traefik.port=8080'
#      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:webgrind.sub.domian.co.nz'
#    volumes:
#      - files:/mnt/files

  #mailhog:
   #image: mailhog/mailhog
    #labels:
     # - 'traefik.backend=mailhog'
      #- 'traefik.port=8025'
      #- 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mailhog.sub.domian.co.nz'

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    command: --no-auth -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=portainer'
      - 'traefik.port=9000'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.sub.domain.co.nz'

  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --logLevel=INFO
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
#      - '8080:8080' # Dashboard
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

volumes:
  codebase:
## Docker-sync for macOS users
#  docker-sync:
#    external: true
## For Xdebug profiler
#  files:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp
```

The `0.0.0.0` means "all IPv4 interfaces" on the host. That includes loopback (127.0.0.1), as well as any other IP's you have (LAN, Wifi).

The `8000->80/tcp` means docker will forward requests on TCP port 8000 of the host to TCP port 80 of your container.

You should be able to connect with http://127.0.0.1:8000 to traefik.

Comment: Cheers I understand that now however as I have commented below:

I get that now however its on an external server. How can I make it so I can access via server IP and therefore portainer.sub.domain.co.nz:8000. The subdomain is pointing to the server IP already

Comment: @JessMcKenzie If you have updated DNS for portainer.sub.domain.co.nz to point to your server, then you should be able to reach it on port 8000. We'd need to know what sort of connection problem you are seeing to know if it is a firewall issue, or if you've made it to traefik and now need to configure that to talk to your container.

Comment: I am getting portainer.sub.domain.co.nz refused to connect.

Comment: If you can successfully `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000` on the server, then it sounds like you have a firewall problem.

Comment: that gives me 404 for some reason

Comment: @JessMcKenzie That's expected, traefik doesn't have anywhere to forward your request and no content on the traefik server itself. You have a firewall issue blocking your browser. To see traefik route a request, include the hostname in your request: `curl -H 'Host: portainer.sub.domain.co.nz' http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Answer (score 0):

```
0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp
```

That means your container is running on localhost, the target port 8000 and publish 80, you can access your wordpress by:

```
http://localhost
http://127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I get that now however its on an external server.  How can I make it so I can access via server IP and therefore  http://portainer.sub.domain.co.nz:8000.  The subdomain is pointing to the server IP already